# How can I reduce the variables used in this code?

Tags: c#

I am trying to reduce the amount of variables used in the code below.
Ideally I would like to keep reusing the string variable `LatestRipMe` without creating the `LatestRipMeVersion string[]` variable.
Do I need to create an array in order to do `Skip(1)` and `First()`?
Can I reach the final value of `LatestRipMe` more efficiently?

```
private void RipMeGetLatestVersion_Process()
{
    //Get the .json file and save it in LatestRipMe string
    LatestRipMe = ClientRipMe.DownloadString("http://www.rarchives.com/ripme.json");

    //Create an array from the previously saved string, and skip the first line
    LatestRipMeVersion = LatestRipMe.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).Skip(1).ToArray();

    //Put the array back in a string, and select only the first line
    LatestRipMe = LatestRipMeVersion.First();

    //The characters which need to be removed
    char[] LatestRipMeTrim = { ' ', ' ', '"', 'l', 'a', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'V', 'e', 'r', 's', 'i', 'o', 'n', '"', ' ', ':', ' ', '"', '"', ',' };

    //Trim the above declared characters
    LatestRipMe = LatestRipMe.Trim(LatestRipMeTrim);

    //Show the remaining string content in the TextBlock
    LatestRipMeVersionText.Text = "Latest RipMe version: " + LatestRipMe;
}
```

Comment: Well aside from anything else, you could start using a JSON parser to parse JSON. That would make the code *much* more obvious...

Comment: A code is not complex or even inperformant (if this is your actual question) because of too many variables. Variables are a good thing as they give a name to the things you´re doing and thus increase code-understanding. Reducing them should therefor not be your main topic.

Comment: If you don't want to heed Jon's insightful advice I suppose one could employ a multi-line regular expression. You read the all the lines anyway, so the string does certainly contain the version. Also, error handling will be better in case the input is not what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet! I downloaded this json parser: https://dynamicjson.codeplex.com/!  
So much easier!

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking - there almost no variables in code you've posted (looks like most are fields of your class), it is unclear what the purpose of the code, it is unclear why would you use char manipulation to parse JSON... Even if code would have variables - what's wrong with having them?

Comment: @Dyon The defacto-standard parser everyone uses is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json Even Microsoft uses it as the default parser in newly created MVC projects in ASP.NET

Comment: Btw.: You should not use `Trim` to delete one character after the other in order to delete whole words. Simple use `Replace("latest", "")` and `Replace("Version", "")`instead.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the json? And can you specify what part of that you want to select? I think it would be easier to help you with more details

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think dissecting an operation by dividing it into steps whose result is stored in throwaway-variables is mainly good for debugging. (That is, of course, a value.) Whether it aids understanding is doubtful though. One prime requirement is proper naming. To assign the actual version string to `LatestRipMe` (re-using the variable) is misleading. To assign all lines but the first to `LatestRipMeVersion` is misleading, too (I would expect the version proper in there).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Alright, I will switch to Newtonsoft.Json than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
  //Create an array from the previously saved string, and skip the first line
  LatestRipMeVersion = LatestRipMe.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).Skip(1).ToArray();

  //Put the array back in a string, and select only the first line
  LatestRipMe = LatestRipMeVersion.First();
```

with

```
  LatestRipMe = LatestRipMe.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())[1];
```

or even

```
  LatestRipMe = LatestRipMe
           .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())[1]
           .Trim(new char[] { ' ', 'a', 'b' });  // etc ...
```

Opinion:
Style wise, that is ugly, difficult to debug and and will throw an exception the site doesn't return what you expect (no internet connection, etc).  I don't really understand the desire to replace your clear, documented step by step code just to reduce the number of variables unless its for a programming challenge.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great answer to my question :)
However as Jon Skeet suggested above, I will use a json parser. But your answer will definitely help me in the future.

Comment: "I don't really understand the desire to replace your clear" However you answer it although it is "ugly, difficult to debug and and will throw an exception"...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void RipMeGetLatestVersion_Process()
{
    LatestRipMe = ClientRipMe.DownloadString("http://www.rarchives.com/ripme.json");

    LatestRipMeVersion = LatestRipMe.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())[1];

    LatestRipMe = LatestRipMe.Trim("  \"latestVersion\" : \"\",".ToCharArray());

    LatestRipMeVersionText.Text = "Latest RipMe version: " + LatestRipMe;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want but be aware that there is a lot that could go wrong with this code.

```
private void RipMeGetLatestVersion_Process()
    {
        LatestRipMeVersion = ClientRipMe
            .DownloadString("http://www.rarchives.com/ripme.json")
            .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
            .Skip(1)
            .ToArray();

        LatestRipMe = LatestRipMeVersion.First()
            .Trim(' ', ' ', '"', 'l', 'a', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'V', 'e', 
            'r', 's', 'i', 'o', 'n', '"', ' ', ':', ' ', '"', '"', ',');
        LatestRipMeVersionText.Text = "Latest RipMe version: " + LatestRipMe;
    }
```

Comment: You assume that `LatestRipMeVersion` isn't required elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As lot of people have already told you, there are way too many things wrong with this code. You should use a JSON parser and follow some standard conventions for naming and structuring the code. I have a feeling that your code still does not do what you want it to do. Look at my version below which does what you want correctly (fetch the value of attribute latestVersion from the json). By no stretch of imagination this is good code, but a lot better than what you have

```
static void Caller() {
    LatestRipMeVersionText.Text = "Latest RipMe version: " + GetLatestVersion();
}

private string GetLatestVersion() {
    var ripmeJson = ClientRipMe.DownloadString("http://www.rarchives.com/ripme.json").      //Get the .json file and save it in LatestRipMe string
        Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].     // convert to an array and pick the 2nd element
        Split(':')[1].Trim('"', ',', ' ');                                                  // fetch the value part

    return ripmeJson;
}
```